# Apply on a dataframe columns returning unexpected results

Tags: python, dataframe, apply, reshape

I have created 2 snippets of code below. Method 2 works but Method 1 is returning unexcepted 0's / large numbers and would like to figure out why.

The codde creates a list of dataframes of certain row and col length (7 x 12) from each column of a dataframe.

I may be wrong but I would have thought method 1 would be faster / more efficient? In any case could you help me understand why method 1 does not work? ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(20, 10)))
l1, l2 = [], []

# Method 1
rand.apply(lambda x: l1.append(pd.DataFrame(x.values.reshape(4, 5))), axis=0)

# Method 2
for c in range(10):
    l2.append(pd.DataFrame(rand.iloc[:, c].values.reshape(4, 5)))
```

My results are:

l1[0]

```
               0              1              2              3              4
0  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311
1  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311
2  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311
3  1.321088e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311  1.321089e-311
```

l2[0]

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.787913 -0.650952 -0.202825  1.004026  0.117248
1 -0.678082  0.939047  0.483811  0.798136 -0.682002
2  0.159300 -0.168461  1.093911  0.417964 -1.601448
3  0.842667  1.602691  0.898461 -0.797576  1.622104
```

Note - have made small edit to variable names for clarity.

Kind regards

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `append` does not return the list itself, it returns `None`, which raises the question why "Method 1 is returning unexcepted 0's / large numbers"? It should actually return a DF with `None` for each column.

A simple way to fix your problem, is turn your `lambda` into a function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(84, 10)))
mtx1, mtx2 = [], []

def my_lambda(x):
    mtx1.append(pd.DataFrame(x.values.reshape(7, 12)))
    return mtx1

# Method 1
rand.apply(my_lambda, axis=0)
```

Comment: Hi Lucas - many thanks for your response. But unfortunately does not solve the problem. Get the same unexpected results I was previously getting.

Comment: Could you please add the resulting DFs to your question?

Comment: Have added. Hopefully helpful. Thanks for your help!